# DIN 5008 zu Anlagen

Tags: spelling, letter

Dürfen laut der DIN 5008 Anlagen aufgezählt werden? Oder wird nur das Wort Anlagen ohne tatsächliche Aufzählung angeführt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Der normative Text der DIN 5008 geht auf die Unterschiede der möglichen Anlagenvermerke nicht explizit ein. Allerdings enthält der informative Anhang E verschiedene Anwendungsbeispiele:

> **Anlage**
>   1 Prospekt

> **Anlage**

> Anlage

> **Anlagen**
>   1  Lichtbild
>   1 Europäischer Lebenslauf
>   4 Zeugniskopien
>   1 Teilnahmebescheinigung

> **Anlage**
>   Kopie der Rechnung

Comment: Danke schön. Und was macht man, wenn man diese Norm nicht kaufen kann? (wenn ich mich nicht vertue, muss man dafür bezahlen) :-)

Comment: @c.p. Dann macht man es wie wahrscheinlich die Mehrheit der Deutschen “irgendwie”. Wer es wissen muss, hat es hoffentlich in der Ausbildung oder so gelernt.